# SQL Server stored procedure delete statement

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, join

I wish to delete a result a select statement returns, reason I'm doing this is because I have relationships between tables and if I delete from the top-most table its children rows in other tables have to be deleted, too.

Can anyone correct this stored procedure for me please?

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[storedprocname] 
    (@Parameter uniqueidentifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
AS BEGIN
    DELETE FROM TableOne 
    WHERE IDOne IN
        (SELECT
           IDOne,
           DescOne, IndexOne,
           IDTwo,
           QuestionTwo, ControlTypeTwo, IndexTwo,
           IDThree,
           DescThree, IndexThree,
           QuestionFour,
           OptionFour
    FROM
           TableOne
        INNER JOIN 
           TableTwo ON TableTwo.CatID = TableOne.IDOne
        INNER JOIN 
           TableThree ON TableThree.Question = TableTwo.IDTwo
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
           TableFour ON TableFour.Question = TableThree.IDThree
        WHERE
           TableOne.IDOne = @Parameter)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[storedprocname] 
  (@Parameter uniqueidentifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
AS BEGIN
  DELETE FROM TableOne 
    WHERE IDOne IN
      (SELECT
         IDOne
       FROM
         TableOne
       INNER JOIN 
         TableTwo ON TableTwo.CatID = TableOne.IDOne
       INNER JOIN 
         TableThree ON TableThree.Question = TableTwo.IDTwo
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
         TableFour ON TableFour.Question = TableThree.IDThree
       WHERE
         TableOne.IDOne = @Parameter)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to delete all rows where `IDOne` is in a list of possible values - then you need to make sure the subquery after the `IN (...)` also returns **a single column** which can be used to compare! After all, you cannot compare a single `IDOne` value to the whole list of columns that you're currently returning ....

Try something like this:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[storedprocname] 
    (@Parameter uniqueidentifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
AS BEGIN
    DELETE FROM TableOne 
    WHERE IDOne IN
        (SELECT
           IDOne
         FROM
           TableOne
        INNER JOIN 
           TableTwo ON TableTwo.CatID = TableOne.IDOne
        INNER JOIN 
           TableThree ON TableThree.Question = TableTwo.IDTwo
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
           TableFour ON TableFour.Question = TableThree.IDThree
        WHERE
           TableOne.IDOne = @Parameter)
END
```

I don't know (your question is too vague and not clear enough) whether all those `JOIN`'s inside the subquery are really needed .... you might need to tweak that to your requirements.